# iOS swift - Lost Connection EXCEPTION

Tags: xcode, swift, exception

when run my project on xcode throw exception (Lost Connection)
how to solve this exception, AND what happen to make this crash.
i am work on XCode 6.4, and cable connect with device by good cable.

**EDIT**

i'm work on append images of type CIImage in NSMutuleArray
memory retch to 12 mb and cpu 17% then throw this exception.
BUT throw this message in console ([8731:1290498] Received memory warning.)

[This image to exception](http://postimg.org/image/ad5cgm4tz/)

Comment: Does your app appear on the device when this happens?  Can you run it without Xcode?  Are there any messages in the device console log?

Comment: when run without xcode throw crash, and not make any message in console log

Comment: Show the crash log...with symbols.

Comment: don't appear any message in console, why happen this exception??

Comment: You said there was a crash.  Please show the symbolicated crash log.  (Use Xcode's Devices window and click "View Device Logs".)

Comment: Device Logs not have any message related my project run, what can i do  to solve this exception?

Comment: sorry, i am seen the messge in device log but i am not understand this message !!